Android HereMaps SDK: Why it deletes map data?
Got information from the user that map was not showing (the route only is shown)

And map data were replaced from
'...\ocm-map\ARCHIVES'
to
"...\ocm-map\ARCHIVES\removed". (The user didn't replace them)
Why HereMaps could replace the data?
(May be it replaces data from ARCHIVE to '/remove' and then should download new data and store it to ARCHIVE. But for some reason not downloading. Internet connection was ok on the user phone)
In logs i see PersistentMapStatus.CORRUPTED status and after that PersistentMapRepairError.INVALID_PATH (coming from
mapDownloader.repairPersistentMap { error -> ... } )

How to fix CORRUPTED (or PENDING_UPDATE) status?
In HereMaps doc it was proposed to fix it with repairing map. But it didn't help and returns INVALID_PATH.
I was able to reproduce PENDING_UPDATE status when made 'Force Stop' for the app when downloading in the app. And later got CORRUPTED status. The user didn't do 'Force Stop' before getting CORRUPTED.
The dev guide says (https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/sdk-for-android-navigate-api-reference/page/com/here/sdk/maploader/PersistentMapRepairError.html#INVALID_PATH)
"The provided path to store the persistent map data doesn't own the required Read/Write (RW) permissions. Try to choose a different path with RW permissions."
What could be the reason that the data doesn't own?
This map data were written there in the path. If it was written so this path owned write permissions! So does it mean it lost the permissions? Another thought that may be it lost permission because MapDownloader at that moment downloading map data so it owns the path. It continues for a long time so on trying to read map to show it at this moment the pass is owned by MapDownloader.
Unfortunately I can't check it because can't reproduce the case that map is not showing.
